# How do I call a method in webforms with $.Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I have a file "File.aspx" and "File.aspx.cs" in "File.aspx.cs" I have method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DeleteModelingReport()
{
    throw new Exception(fileName);
}
```

And in "File.aspx" I have $.Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/File.aspx/DeleteModelingReport/") %>',
                success: function () { console.log("File Deleted") },


            });
```

But for some reason $.ajax is not calling that method and I can'f figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Any exception in the response (using fiddler or other dev tools)?

Comment: If you haven't already, install fiddler and let us know what error the request produces.

Comment: I'm getting response in the console log "File Deleted", I don't have fiddler installed but no errors in the console log

Comment: when I try to go directly to that URL in the web browser File.aspx/DeleteModelingReport/ I'm being redirected to another page and Visual Studio is not firing off any exceptions. Even though I have throw exception in that method.

Comment: Method in code behind must be marked `static`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out had to add [ScriptMethod] to the method DeleteModelingReport